# Django REST Framework URLPathVersioning not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, api-versioning

I followed the guide [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/#urlpathversioning) to add versioning to our API. This is what the `urls.py` looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from api import views

urlpatterns = [    url(
        r'^(?P<version>(v1|v2))/foo/bar',
        views.foo_bar,
    ),
]
```

However, when I hit my API with the URL `http://localhost:5555/v1/foo/bar` I get an error:

```
TypeError at /v1/foo/bar
foo_bar() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your `foo_bar` view does not accept the argument `version`.

It needs to be defined as:

```
def foo_bar(request, version):
    ...
```